# How to set up rotating wallpapers through GPO

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy, desktop

So, my guestion is "easy" in nature, not so easy in solution...

my boss came up with a brilliant idea of having wallpapers changed every 30 minutes or 1 hour or something. In short, he wants active desktop from windows 7 but this pushed through a GPO.

For windows XP machines we would like this to work as well, but if we can get it working on windows 7 machines for now that'd be great.

anyone able to point me to a guide, how to, or tell me how to get started on this and where to find the right option to do this in the GPO's ?

Cheers

Comment: Any idea why your boss wants this? Is it to improve productivity or operational efficiency or just because it's "kool"?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're being facetious or not with using the word 'brilliant' about your boss' idea.  I personally think it's pretty dumb, but I digress.  Why not just let your users choose which wallpaper they'd like to use?

Comment: That seems like a waste of IT resources. Perhaps someone should tell your boss that you may have more productive things to focus on :)

Comment: Let me guess, your boss wants to cycle pictures of HIS kids through every 30 minutes on all the machines? ;)

Comment: The word *brilliant* reminded me of [Paula Beans](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Brillant_Paula_Bean.aspx) :-)

Comment: I can see the use for laptops which are used in sales or other places where outsiders will catch a glimpse of them and their background... branding is important imho though changing the logon/lock screen seems more neutral (and is supported in Windows 7).

Comment: Point out to your boss that anyone working on a computer shouldn't even see the wallpaper. Oddly enough, that's not where the work happens.

Comment: I was being sarcastic when I said brillaint, but the bottomline is, I find it stupid, a waste, my collegues find it stupid and a waste... but the boss is the boss so... I need to get this done ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easy.  Although, as many have commented, it could be particularly irritating to users.

1. Create your customized theme.
2. Deploy the custom theme to clients, including wallpaper images.
3. Configure Group Policy to select your custom theme.

The .theme file format is fully documented in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190(VS.85).aspx).  You will be particularly interested in the [Slide Show section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190%28VS.85%29.aspx#slideshow_settings).  The Group Policy option titled *"[Load a specific theme](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617164%28WS.10%29.aspx)"* can be used to select your theme.  There is also a policy option to disable users from changing the theme.

Comment: Whether theme pack will work for windows 10. I want change the wallapaper every month using GPO. i have mixed environment of windows 7 and windows 10 clients

Answer (score -2):

just copy your image to share folder which everyone PC can read, the named it picture1 to picture*n*, and make batch file to rename it every 30 minute, rotate name but it need manual refresh walpaper on client with lock or logout, i just searching too how to use like windows 7 theme rotate